# d3.json albers projection and US ecoregions

Tags: d3.js, topojson

I have a topojson file which I created using mapshaper online tool.  I downloaded the original shapefile from ftp://newftp.epa.gov/EPADataCommons/ORD/Ecoregions/us/
(us_eco_l3.zip).  I've used ESRI's ArcMap 10.2 to "dissolve" the shapefile so I ended up with 85 unique ecoregions.  I then used mapshaper (http://www.mapshaper.org/) to convert the shapefile into topojson file.

However, I can't get the topojson file to display properly in my web page.  I suspect my projection is wrong.  But I can't figure out where I am going wrong.

Below is my code in my web page (I'm using ASP.NET MVC 5):

```
<style>
.region {
    stroke: #fff;
    fill: #005DAA;
}

.hover {
    fill: yellow;
}

.selected{
    stroke: #fff;
    fill: #00C800;
}

#regName{
    position: absolute;
    top:  150px;
    height: 22px;
    width: 250px;
    padding: 3px;
    text-align:center;        
}
```

```
<input type="text" id="regName" disabled />
<div id="map" style="text-align:center">
    <h1>US Ecoregions Level III</h1>
    <h3 id="reg"></h3>    
</div>

<script src="//d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script src="//d3js.org/topojson.v1.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var width = 960,
        height = 400,
        centered;

    var projection = d3.geo.albers()
        .center([-96.5, 38.68])  
        .scale(1000)
        .rotate([0, 0]);

    var path = d3.geo.path()
        .projection(projection);

    var svg = d3.select("#map").append("svg")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height);

    queue()
      .defer(d3.json, "/topo/ecol3.json")
      .await(ready);

    function ready(error, us) {
        svg.append("g")
            .selectAll("path")
            .data(topojson.feature(us, us.objects.ecol3).features)
        .enter()
            .append("path")
            .attr("d", path)
            .attr("class", "region")
            .on("mouseover", function (d) {
                d3.select("h3").text(d.properties.US_L3NAME);
                d3.select(this).attr("class", "region hover");
            })
            .on("mouseout", function (d) {
               d3.select("h3").text("");
               d3.select(this).attr("class", "region");
           })
           .on("click", function (d) {
               var name = d.properties.US_L3NAME;
               var region = d3.select("#regName");
               region.property("value", name);
           });
    }
</script>
```

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues that are causing problems with displaying your geographic data.

1. Your data is projected onto a planar surface already, D3 projections take latitude and longitudes representing points on a spheroid and project them onto a planar surface. You can see that the data is already projected in the `.prj` file that is part of the shapefile:

   `PROJCS["USA_Contiguous_Albers_Equal_Area_Conic_USGS_version",...`

You can fix this in ArcMap by using the project tool (ArcToolbox->Data Management->Projections and Transformations->Project) and set the projection to WGS84. Or, in MapShaper (ensure you copy in the prj file into the window as well), in the console type `proj wgs84`.

D3 requires data to be in lat long format, WGS84 is most ideal, though using NAD83 as your datum isn't likely to produce any problems (especially in North America).

---

2. Your projection parameters are set incorrectly for an Albers projection. If you set an Albers projection to have a [0,0] rotation and centering point (and zoom out to something liked `.scale(150)`), you will get something like:

[image]

```
d3.geo.albers()
  .rotation([0,0])
  .center([0,0])
```

If you only use center to focus on your area of interest, you will simply pan this image to your area of interest, and naturally, the US will be rotated in a manner that is most likely not desired. Instead you want to rotate the globe by longitude so that your area of interest is vertically aligned in the middle. For the US you want to spin the globe 100 degrees underneath the projection (so that -100 degrees is now in the center and the meridian at -100 is vertical). Because you are spinning the earth, you want the negative of the longitude you are focusing on. By applying a rotation of [100,0] we get something like:

[image]

```
d3.geo.projection()
  .rotation([100,0])
  .center([0,0])
```

Now you can pan up down by the y axis to find your area of interest. And of course, zoom in all you need with an appropriate scale factor.

*If you center on the x now, say to -50, you are centering it relative to your rotation, which has placed the prime meridian at 100 degrees west, so you would actually be centering on 150 degrees west)*

An Albers projection also sets parallels, the lines on a globe which intersect a conical projection, like an Albers, placed over it like a hat. These should be in your area of interest, but not the northern and southern extremes, as distortion is minimized on either side of them. All together this gives you a form like:

```
d3.geo.albers()
  .parallels([a,b])
  .center([0,y])
  .rotate([-x,0])
```

However, saying all this, the default Albers projection in d3 (v3 at least), is focused on the United States:

[image]

This is simply based on : `var projection = d3.geo.albers()`

*It is also possible to use projected data, but this approach is less common and does not mesh as well with other data that requires projection*

Comment: You were very helpful.  Answers everything I needed.  It works now. Thank you very much.  I reprojected my shapefile to Geographic Coordinate System WGS 84 and re-exported it to topojson using mapshaper.  You really saved me!